# How search first position on SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have problem, I can't search value position in my table. For example: I have table:

```
ProdID  InstID  APY
C3M2.5K 11920   0.3
C3M2.5K 11246   0.25
C3M2.5K 11626   0.25
C3M2.5K 12081   0.15
C3M2.5K 11224   0.05
C3M2.5K 11311   0.05
C3M2.5K 11460   0.05
C3M2.5K 11164   0.03
C3M2.5K 11394   0.01
```

Code:

```
select * from table
where APY = 0.05
```

I need write select which will be display: 
Count(APY) - it's: 9
First position APY - it's: 5
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Positon according to which column(s)? How do you want to order?

Comment: I can add the id to the table

Comment: this table generate using t-sql

Comment: Yes, you should show the ID, otherwise your desired result seems to be arbitrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT CountAPY = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TableName),
          Pos = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID),
          ProdID, InstID, APY
   FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT TOP 1 CountAPY, FirstPos = Pos
FROM CTE
WHERE APY = 0.05
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a4f22/1/0

Comment: Hi @Yura, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.